What could be causing drywall tape to buckle?
I’ve lived in this house for 2 years. The house was built 25 years ago. I just noticed in one corner on the ground level that the drywall tape is buckling. It’s possible it has always been like this, as it’s in a hallway where we rarely turn the lights on, but I do usually notice things like this which makes me think it happened recently. The ridges do not give under pressure so it doesn’t seem like there’s moisture underneath but I could be wrong. Would appreciate any advice on what could cause this and if it’s something to be concerned about. Thanks!


That's a shape unlike anything I've seen before, and I've seen a lot of messed up drywall. Are you sure it's not impact damage? Looks like someone was leaning something there.

UPDATE:
I think @RMDman is right, water intrusion could be the reason for those winkles.  Do what he suggests and look for other areas that might have been affected.  But once you are sure that the water won't return, then the advice on how to fix it still holds.
ORIGINAL ANSWER:
Looks to me like it's just a bad taping job.  The wrinkles you see are the joint tape that was not properly smoothed out when the joint was originally mudded and taped.  If there is no "give" in those wrinkles, then it is probably stable and it's only an aesthetic concern.
If the wrinkles were appearing right in the corner between the two perpendicular walls, then that could be a sign of the walls shifting relative to each other which could indicate a structural concern.  But I don't see any evidence of that in the picture.
If the aesthetics concern you, then it can be repaired by slicing open the wrinkles with a utility knife and cutting out any of the paper tape that sticks up.  Once the paper tape is relatively flat, then mud over it with joint compound.  If any of the paper tape is not adhered to the drywall, then you'll need to force some joint compound underneath the tape that is loose.  Insufficient mud on the drywall before applying the tape over it could have contributed to the problem you are seeing.  After that, let it dry, sand flat, then prime and paint.

Wrinkles, like what you have, is a sign of water intrusion and usually is the paint pulling away from the drywall.
If the wrinkles are not soft, it is most likely that water had gotten into the area and has dried up. This leaves the wrinkled paint to dry and feel hard.
Before enacting a repair, ( Which would be cutting out the wrinkles, spackling and repainting.) you should check all the walls and ceiling in the surrounding area for additional signs of water intrusion.
Things to look for are stains, bulges or bubbles and of course wrinkles.  Be sure to inspect in bright light. Some stains are very subtle and only seen in certain light.

It’s actually an inside corner, maybe hard to tell from the photo. Previous water intrusion would make sense though. There’s roof just above this, and we had a hurricane come through in early October. There was another spot in a different room where water came in during the hurricane but not in any of the normal rains since. I bet this is also what happened here. Thanks!

I got hit with the Hurricanes too.  In many instances my neighbors had the water intrusion, that never happened before as well.   It is just a matter of repair, but look for stains on the ceiling.
